# No Activity found to handle Intent for Default Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I get error `No Activity found to handle Intent` when I try to start Default Activity from another Activity using

```
Intent start = new Intent("com.name.name.MainActivity");
startActivity(start);
finish();
```

I guess this is because in AndroidManifest for Default Activity I have `android.intent.action.MAIN`

```
  <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Is there a way to start Default Activity from another Activity when Default Activity is finished before?

Comment: you need something like sharedpreference.. like after the first activity save a sharedpreference stating that you have finished launching that activity for the first time and in onResume of the firstactivity goes the checking of your sharedpreference if true, then start your second activity otherwise no

Comment: Please show the full manifest

Comment: Read docs ... what is a string parameter of Intent constructor with only one parameter? I'm sure that not component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to start the activity using the action name..

**Note**:`startActivity()` always adds `CATEGORY_DEFAULT` to an `Intent` if there is no other category specified(Here you have no category specified in your internt so its default).

Hence, an `<intent-filter>` for an `<activity>` always needs a `<category>`, whether `DEFAULT` or something else (here it needs default that's why error says *No Activity found to handle Intent for Default Activity*)

**The LAUNCHER** category says that this entry point should be listed in the application launcher.

**The DEFAULT** category is required for the `Context.startActivity()` method to resolve your activity when its component name is not explicitly specified.

Try to specify two intent filters:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.name.name.MainActivity"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then you can start the activity using the action name:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.name.name.MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

or simply you can go with the class name:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

Intent i = new Intent(otheractivity.this, MainActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);